# Traversing jQuery object to populate multi-level nav

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have the following object which I'm using to populate my navigation bar:

```
var navLinks = {
    'Products':     ['ProductCategory1', 'ProductCategory2'],
    'Collections':  ['Collection1'],
    'About':        ['AboutSection1', 'AboutSection2']
};
```

Top level of nav is populated as such:

```
$.each(navLinks, function(key, value) {
    $('#site-nav').append('<ul class="' + key + ' nav-first-level"><a href="../' + key + '">' + key + '</a><ul class="nav-second-level"></ul></ul>');
});
```

I would like the arrays within each key/value pair to populate a second level of my nav by inserting titles within the `<ul class="nav-second-level"></ul>` element, however not sure of best way to approach this.

Comment: Just... do another nested loop over `value`?

Comment: @jszobody How would I go about setting that up?